# atomic_inc and atomic_xchg in gcc assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

I have written the following user-level code snippet to test two sub functions, atomic `inc` and `xchg` (refer to Linux code).
What I need is just try to perform operations on 32-bit integer, and that's why I explicitly use `int32_t`.
I assume `global_counter` will be raced by different threads, while `tmp_counter` is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t global_counter = 10;

/* Increment the value pointed by ptr */
void atomic_inc(int32_t *ptr)
{
    __asm__("incl %0;\n"
        : "+m"(*ptr));
}

/* 
 * Atomically exchange the val with *ptr.
 * Return the value previously stored in *ptr before the exchange
 */
int32_t atomic_xchg(uint32_t *ptr, uint32_t val)
{
    uint32_t tmp = val;
    __asm__(
        "xchgl %0, %1;\n"
        : "=r"(tmp), "+m"(*ptr)
        : "0"(tmp)
        :"memory");
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int32_t tmp_counter = 0;

    printf("Init global=%d, tmp=%d\n", global_counter, tmp_counter);

    atomic_inc(&tmp_counter);
    atomic_inc(&global_counter);
    printf("After inc, global=%d, tmp=%d\n", global_counter, tmp_counter);

    tmp_counter = atomic_xchg(&global_counter, tmp_counter);
    printf("After xchg, global=%d, tmp=%d\n", global_counter, tmp_counter);

    return 0;
}
```

My 2 questions are:

1. Are these two subfunctions written properly?
2. Will this behave the same when I compile this on 32-bit or
   64-bit platform? For example, could the pointer address have a different
   length. or could `incl` and `xchgl` will conflict with the operand?

Comment: Do not dereference `ptr` when you use it in a memory operand constraint.

Comment: Unlike `xchg`, `inc` is not atomic by default. You'd need a `lock` prefix.

Comment: Since inline asm is already gcc-specific, you might as well use gcc atomic builtins instead. At least those will work under x86-64 or even other architectures too.

Comment: Hi, Michael, but why can Linux deference the ptr in http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg_64.h#L20? What's the risk of doing this?

Comment: As harold said, the inc should be
        __asm__("lock;\n"
                "incl %0;\n"
                : "+m"(*ptr));

Comment: Thanks, Jester. I will look into this (but this small practice is also interesting to me)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of this question is below, please correct me if I'm wrong.

All the read-modify-write instructions (ex: incl, add, xchg) need a lock prefix. The lock instruction is to lock the memory accessed by other CPUs by asserting LOCK# signal on the memory bus.

The __xchg function in Linux kernel implies no "lock" prefix because xchg always implies lock anyway. http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg_64.h#L15

However, the incl used in atomic_inc does not have this assumption so a lock_prefix is needed.
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h#L105

btw, I think you need to copy the *ptr to a volatile variable to avoid gcc optimization.

William